# Show a element only on mobile view

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want just to show a text element if a link is clicked in the mobile view. I'm pretty sure I have a syntax error in here but I don't know where.

```
$("#Link1").click( function()
{
if($(window).width() > 800 )
  {
   $("#Text1").show();
  }
});
```

Comment: `$(window).width() < 800 `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a syntax error but logical error! Try replacing `>` with `<`:

```
$("#Link1").click( function() {
  if($(window).width() < 800 ) {
   $("#Text1").show();
  }
});
```